# Object required error '424'

Tags: excel, vba

There are hyperlink formulas in column A.  =HYPERLINK("http://localhost:60151/load?file=file:///L:/all_runs_10_12_2015-151121/bam/Horizon_mutation_P72R.bam&goto&locus=chr17:7579422-7579522","P72R")

If a corresponding cell in column B (same row) is not blank I would like to replace the label of the formula with whatever is in column B.

I get an error '424' Object required at `cl.Formula = Left(cl.Formula, CommaPos + 1) & cel.Offset(0, 1).Value & """)"`  Please see my code below and help to figure out what I’m missing.

Thanks

```
Sub SpecialLoop()

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim CommaPos As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long


    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each cl In rng

If Not (IsEmpty(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value)) Then

     CommaPos = InStr(cl.Formula, ",")

    cl.Formula = Left(cl.Formula, CommaPos + 1) & cel.Offset(0, 1).Value & """)"
End If

    Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: `cel` looks like a typo. Read about `Option Explicit` to avoid it in future.

Comment: @BrakNicku Good eyes. user3781528, it is an excellent idea to set your editor options once and for all to always enforce variable declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond getting the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor ► Require Variable Declaration set, there are some loose ends in the remainder of your code that could cause problems.

You know your own data and formula structure better than most but there is no guarantee that the optional *[friendly_name]* parameter exists. I would recommend using the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) to isolate the required *link_location* parameter of the [HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F) instead.

Consistency in the method used to reference the parent worksheet would help this short sub. I would use a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to specifically reference either the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or a Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) but not half of one and half of the other.

```
Sub SpecialLoop()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lr As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lr)

        For Each cl In rng
            If Not IsEmpty(cl.Offset(0, 1)) And _
              Left(cl.Formula, 11) = "=HYPERLINK(" Then
                cl.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & _
                             Split(cl.Formula, Chr(34))(1) & Chr(34) & _
                             Chr(44) & Chr(34) & cl.Offset(0, 1).Value2 & Chr(34) & Chr(41)
            End If
        Next cl
    End With

End Sub
```